# Trying to upgrade to laravel 5.3 but I keep seeing error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate::abilities()`

Tags: php, laravel, symfony, laravel-5

I am trying to upgrade laravel 5.3 from 5.2 but I keep seeing these two errors in my log file:

`Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate::abilities() in /Users/rohan0793/Code/poptin_v3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:237`

And this one:

`Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Log\Writer::setHandlers() in Command line code:1`

Full stack outputs:

```
[2020-08-13 08:26:58] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate::abilities() in /Users/rohan0793/Code/poptin_v3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:237
Stack trace:
#0 Command line code(1): Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::__callStatic('abilities', Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /Users/rohan0793/Code/poptin_v3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:237
```

```
[2020-08-13 08:26:58] local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Log\Writer::setHandlers() in Command line code:1
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: VscodeLaravelExtraIntellisenseProvider->boot()
#1 /Users/rohan0793/Code/poptin_v3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(508): call_user_func_array(Array, Array)
#2 /Users/rohan0793/Code/poptin_v3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(769): Illuminate\Container\Container->call(Array)
#3 /Users/rohan0793/Code/poptin_v3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(752): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootProvider(Object(VscodeLaravelExtraIntellisenseProvider))
#4 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Application->Illuminate\Foundation\{closure}(Object(VscodeLaravelExtraIntellisenseProvider), 2)
#5 /Users/rohan0793/Code/poptin_v3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(753): array_walk(Array, Object(Closure))
#6 /Users/rohan0793/Code/poptin_v3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Bootstrap/BootProviders.php(17): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->boot()
#7 /Users/rohan0793/Code/poptin_v3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(203): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\BootProviders->bootstrap(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application))
#8 /Users/rohan0793/Code/poptin_v3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(267): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->bootstrapWith(Array)
#9 /Users/rohan0793/Code/poptin_v3/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(113): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->bootstrap()
#10 Command line code(1): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
```

I have no idea where these are coming from and how to resolve them.

UPDATE: I see these errors every minute at 41 secs. Example `13:35:41`
But according to my crontab in homestead, I don't have any crons scheduled

UPDATE 2: https://github.com/illuminate/auth/blob/5.5/Access/Gate.php the abilities method is present in 5.5. But I am still at 5.3. Weird but I don't know what is calling that code already. Maybe a third party package.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=amiralizadeh9480.laravel-extra-intellisense

This VS Code extension was causing the 2 errors, and it was trying to compile something every minute and hence it was very confusing and felt like a cron job running in the background.

Comment: som how did you fix the problem?

Comment: I removed the extension lol

Comment: I have the same issue with Laravel 5.4 too.

Answer (score 0):

Try to find on official documentation for upgrade guide. They cover a lot of issues and maybe you find yours. It's a very specific issue and you are missing something in your code, but from a question, we can't know. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.3.0

Also try `Rector` for upgrade or any issue after upgrade https://github.com/rectorphp/rector

Comment: I am done with all the steps and was able to resolve all other errors, except these two. Now when I am digging deeper, it seems like `Gate::abilities` is present in 5.5. But something is already calling that method in 5.3. No idea why. :) The other method, I couldn't find even in future versions.

Comment: Maybe some package? Did you traced where is called?

Comment: Check all imports from https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/5.3/config/app.php